# Referencing property in Gremlin query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm trying to do a query that looks somewhat like this:

```
g.V('myId').as('me').out('member').hasLabel('myLabel').in('member').has('identifier', 'me.identifier')
```

Where me.identifier would be changed to something that actually works. I just have no clue how to reference the property value of "identifier"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first consider what your query:

```
g.V('myId').as('me').
  out('member').hasLabel('myLabel').
  in('member').has('identifier', 'me.identifier')
```

says in English: "find a vertex with the `id` of 'myId', then traverse outgoing 'member' edges to vertices that have the label of 'myLabel', then traverse incoming 'member' edges to vertices that have a property value of 'me.identifier' for the 'identifier' property"

Now, maybe that's not exactly what you want. For some reason, I gather that you want to: "find a vertex with the `id` of 'myId', then traverse outgoing 'member' edges to vertices that have the label of 'myLabel', then traverse incoming 'member' edges to vertices that have an `id` of 'myId'" in which case it's:

```
g.V('myId').
  out('member').hasLabel('myLabel').
  in('member').hasId('myId')
```

But then I also gather than you might want to: "find a vertex with the `id` of 'myId', then traverse outgoing 'member' edges to vertices that have the label of 'myLabel', then traverse incoming 'member' edges to vertices that have an `identifier` property with the same value of as the 'identifier' property of the start vertex with 'myId'" in which case it's:

```
g.V('myId').as('me').
  out('member').hasLabel('myLabel').
  in('member').as('them').
  where('them', eq('me')).
    by('identifier')
```